Zoom meeting SDK with custom UI and in-built option bar
I have integrated Zoom meeting SDK and I need to show some custom UI.
As per documentation provided here. I can still retain the option bar at the bottom along with all the functionality provided but the documentation is vague regarding it.
I am not able to figure out how to get a reference to the meetingOptionBar which I am assuming that is the bottom bar which contains all the functionality.
Any insight on how achieve a custom UI with the default option bar and its functionality?

Check it's sample/example2 in SDK to find the view reference like mAudioStatusImg, mBtnShare, mBtnSwitchCamera, etc. and update then as say in https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/android/use-meeting-sdk/custom-ui/view/meeting-option-bar/#configure-buttons

Hey @Kolyneh, can you provide the link to 'sample/example2'?

I don't have this SDK,  but you can see in in the download guide: https://developers.zoom.us/docs/meeting-sdk/android/get-started/install-sdk/#download-the-meeting-sdk-for-android , they said "Libraries and examples are inside [mobilertc-android-studio] folder".
